# How to avoid website url as variable when use jQuery ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Im face a trouble.

example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSend").click(function () {
        var noti_p = {
            url: "Pusher_Controller.ashx",
            data: "&appname=" + $("#selt1").val() + "&title=" + $("#title").val() + "&body=" + $("#body").val(),
            type: "POST",
            encoding: "UTF-8",
            datatype: "text",
            success: function () { alert('Send Success!'); },
            error: function () { alert('Send Fail'); }
        };
        if ($("#selt1").val() != "Select a App" && $("#title").val() != "" && $("#body").val()) { $.ajax(noti_p); }
        else { alert("project name,title or body are empty"); }
    });
});
```

html part:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="body" name="body" />
```

when I input

```
https://www.example.com/bimVR/bimOBJ-CTM.html?id=gEfqzBtv4NHH0mEamqRibFxuAfxLPD_01&id1=011&note=1&pass=dw%2b%2bFQepY7eCyNlpZDlwy5gx%2feWsrsf2erfqRh13bVK3vkAIElwY%3d
```

In url **&id1=011** will as variable 
but I want send all url to my database.

now in DB its

```
https://www.example.com/bimvr/BIMOBJ-CTM.html?id=gEfqzBtv4NHH0mEamqRibFxuAfxLPD_01
```

hope I description detail enough

Comment: you need to escape the character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all I tried this code and get variables by php and url was ok and complete:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
        serialized_data=escape("http://google.com?id=1&t=1");
        url="test.php";
        jQuery.post(url, serialized_data, function(response) {
            $('#result').html(response)
        })  .fail(function() {

        });
    })
```

and second, you can use for example | instead of & and then replace them in your server side code.

Comment: yes,you just need to replace the characters in server side